# Cannot start Hadoop dameon services

Tags: hadoop

On my Imac,I could run the `bin/start-all.sh` ,and would then start the services by jps command earlier. Now when I run `bin/start-all..sh` it shows me starting `namenode, starting job tracker` etc.but when I type JPS, it gives me some random number and JPS ,n nothing else... I wonder what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

What is output when you try to access any hadoop web gui hostname:50070 etc

Also have you read this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738070/hadoop-cannot-use-jps-command